# Accessing object properties directly in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm getting an JSON array from a service I create which contains a result similar to:

```
[{"_id":"5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001","billName":"Jeep Insurance","startDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2400,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z","__v":0},{"_id":"549bf0597886c3763e000001","billName":"Jeep Leasing","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","amount":16500,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z","__v":0}]
```

Now I would like to also get the sum of the `amount` into the array so I can access it from my view.
Which, look like this:

```
[{"_id":"5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001","billName":"Jeep Insurance","startDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2400,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z","__v":0},{"_id":"549bf0597886c3763e000001","billName":"Jeep Leasing","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","amount":16500,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z","__v":0},{"total":18900}]
```

However, if I display `{{variablename}}` in my view, it returns:

```
[{"_id":"5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001","billName":"Jeep Insurance","startDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2400,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z","__v":0},{"_id":"549bf0597886c3763e000001","billName":"Jeep Leasing","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","amount":16500,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z","__v":0},{"total":18900}]
```

How can I access the `total` value directly?
It doesn't work if I try:

`{{variablename.total}}` for example.

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: It's an array you are trying to access. You'll need something like `variablename[index].total` to access `total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you could restructure the response from API slightly:

API output:

```
{
   "bills" : [],
   "total" :<number>
}
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="bill in scopeModel.bills">{{bill.billName}}</div>
<div>Total: {{scopeModel.total}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array you are trying to access.

**JS File**

```
$scope.variablename = [{"_id":"5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001","billName":"Jeep Insurance","startDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2400,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z","__v":0},{"_id":"549bf0597886c3763e000001","billName":"Jeep Leasing","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","amount":16500,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z","__v":0},{"total":18900}];
```

You can use `ng-repeat` to iterate over the array and print the required values.

**HTML File**

```
<div ng-repeat="singleItem in variablename">
        {{singleItem.total}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass  `variablename`  to totalAmount function or can get it from $scope directly, iterate over each element and add amount in total then return it

**In view**

```
{{totalAmount(variablename)}}
```

**In controller**

```
$scope.totalAmount = function(v){
total=0
v.forEach(function(element){
total +=element.amount; 
})
return total;
}
```

**Alternatively use reduce()**

```
  $scope.variablename= [{"_id":"5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001","billName":"Jeep Insurance","startDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2400,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z","__v":0},{"_id":"549bf0597886c3763e000001","billName":"Jeep Leasing","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","amount":16500,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z","__v":0},{"total":18900}];

  $scope.total = variablename.reduce(function(total,element) {
return total+ element.amount; 
}, 0);
```

In view

```
{{total}}
```